# autofs fails with directories cross-mounted on server until root accesses them

Tags: 16.04, permissions, automount, nfs

*When I try to access a directory which is cross-mounted on the nfs server, the result is an "Operation not permitted" error unless root has accessed the directory recently. If the directory is not touched for the timeout period, users cannot access it again until root has.*

I have an nfs server which I use for AV media, serving web pages and so forth.  Its name is hamlet, running debian, and it has (LVM) partitions for /export/web and others. The Xenial client cannot traverse the exported directory hierarchy, although other clients can.

On the server:

```
Linux hamlet 3.16.0-4-686-pae #1 SMP Debian 3.16.7-ckt25-2 (2016-04-08) i686
nick@hamlet:~$ cat /etc/exports
/export        172.17.0.0/255.255.0.0(rw,sync,crossmnt,no_subtree_check)
/export/web    172.17.0.0/255.255.0.0(rw,sync,nohide,no_subtree_check)
```

(I understand the `nohide` should be unnecessary but removing it does not fix the error)

On the Xenial desktop machine I have this server mounted under directory /auto:

```
nick@polonius:~$ uname -a
Linux polonius 4.4.0-31-generic #50-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jul 13 00:06:14 UTC 2016 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux
nick@polonius:~$ cat /etc/auto.auto 
# Mount exported directories from Hamlet under /auto
hamlet  -sec=sys,nfsvers=3,noacl        172.17.1.5:/export
```

and in /etc/auto.master I have the line

```
/auto   /etc/auto.auto
```

The problem is that although the top-level automounted directory appears, it isn't possible to change into the directory cross-mounted on the server as an ordinary user.

I also have a Debian laptop with **identical configuration**. This laptop does not have this problem. But on the Ubuntu machine:

```
nick@polonius:~$ ls /auto
nick@polonius:~$ ls /auto/hamlet
archive  children  ebooks  iPlayer  media  photos  web
nick@polonius:~$ ls /auto/hamlet/web
ls: cannot open directory '/auto/hamlet/web': Operation not permitted
nick@polonius:~$ sudo ls /auto/hamlet/web
[sudo] password for nick: 
htdocs  lost+found  mail  mail_secrets.php  Thunderbird_Archives
nick@polonius:~$ ls /auto/hamlet/web
htdocs  lost+found  mail  mail_secrets.php  Thunderbird_Archives
```

On a debain laptop:

```
nick@ariel:~$ uname -a
Linux ariel 4.6.0-1-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.6.3-1 (2016-07-04) x86_64 GNU/Linux
nick@ariel:~$ ls /auto
nick@ariel:~$ ls /auto/hamlet
archive  children  ebooks  iPlayer  media  photos  web
nick@ariel:~$ ls /auto/hamlet/web
htdocs  lost+found  mail  mail_secrets.php  Thunderbird_Archives
```

If I run the automounter in the terminal with -f -v, it does not report any issues. Also, when root has accessed the subdirectory causing it to appear, it has the correct permissions.

```
nick@polonius:~$ sudo ls /auto/hamlet/web
htdocs  lost+found  mail  mail_secrets.php  Thunderbird_Archives
nick@polonius:~$ touch /auto/hamlet/web/thing
nick@polonius:~$ ls -l /auto/hamlet/web/thing
-rw-rw-r-- 1 nick nick 0 Jul 24 13:13 /auto/hamlet/web/thing
nick@polonius:~$ rm /auto/hamlet/web/thing
nick@polonius:~$
```

I bet this is my fault, but I've no idea what to change on the Ubuntu machine to get it to work as it should. The Ubuntu client was working until approximately a week ago, so this may be a regression.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Reverting to build 28 of the 4.4.0 kernel causes the issue to cease. Specifically, `Linux 4.4.0-28-generic #47-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jun 24 10:08:35 UTC 2016 i686`

I conclude there is a regression between build 28 and 31 which causes the automounter to malfunction, unless anybody can see something I did wrong in my configuration files (i.e. I'm calling it a bug, you might think it's a feature :) )

Answer (score 0):

I do have a similar setup : Debian 8 file server several Ubuntu/Kubuntu clients. The NFS setup on the file server is also comparable.
The setup has been working for months, but on a certain moment in time it started to fail on all clients. I did  not realized that updates where the cause. 
I have been struggling  for a few weeks ( on and off)  to find one client was working again. 
Updates where applied on all clients. 
Comparing the setups I couldn’t find any differences. 
Comparing “uname -a”:
Non working client : 
“Linux xxxx-pc 4.4.0-31-generic #50-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jul 13 00:07:12 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux”

Working client : 
"Linux xxxx-desktop 4.4.0-33-generic #52-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jul 22 19:16:44 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/L
inux"

It turns out on the working client I was using “xenial-proposed” updates which where updating the kernel. Loading  kernel  4.4.0-33 on a none working client solves the issue.

Comment: 4.4.0-34 got installed here today as a routine upgrade, and the issue is indeed resolved. Thanks, whoever fixed that!